# Error when adding validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar to classpath

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

i try to add validation in Spring MVC project, but when i add the jar:

> validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar

i get this error creating bean exception org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.seprof.service.UserService com.seprof.web.controller.AdminController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.seprof.dao.UserDAO com.seprof.service.UserServiceImpl.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myUserDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myHibernateTemplate' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myHibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1075)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:383)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:362)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:82)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        ... 19 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.seprof.service.UserService com.seprof.web.controller.AdminController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.seprof.dao.UserDAO com.seprof.service.UserServiceImpl.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myUserDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myHibernateTemplate' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myHibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
        ... 39 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.seprof.dao.UserDAO com.seprof.service.UserServiceImpl.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myUserDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myHibernateTemplate' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myHibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
        ... 41 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.seprof.dao.UserDAO com.seprof.service.UserServiceImpl.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myUserDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myHibernateTemplate' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myHibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
        ... 52 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myUserDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myHibernateTemplate' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myHibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
        ... 54 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myHibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 67 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        ... 84 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:118)
        ... 92 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validation
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:380)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:109)
        ... 97 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.Validation
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 99 more
```

i don't know why, any help?

this is the classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre7">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v7.0">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-pool-1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jta-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.context.support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/sitemesh-2.4.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-config-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/standard-1.1.2.jar"/>
```

and this is the application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.orgA/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- Auto-detect components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.seprof.web.controller" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp">
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
<!--        <property name="initialSize" value="20" /> -->
<!--        <property name="maxActive" value="30" /> -->

    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.seprof.pojo.User</value>
                <value>com.seprof.pojo.Role</value>
                <value>com.seprof.pojo.Country</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myHibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="mySessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- DAO -->
    <bean id="myUserDAO" class="com.seprof.dao.UserDAOImpl">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="myHibernateTemplate" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="myCommonDAO" class="com.seprof.dao.CommonDAOImpl">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="myHibernateTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Service -->
    <bean id="userService" class="com.seprof.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="commonService" class="com.seprof.service.CommonServiceImpl">
        <property name="commonDAO" ref="myCommonDAO" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userValidator" class="com.seprof.web.validator.UserValidator" />

    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven /> -->
    <!-- <bean id="transactionManager" -->
    <!-- class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"> -->
    <!-- <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" /> -->
    <!-- </bean> -->
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your have not defined the validation bean used by your sessionFactory bean.

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory

Normally it is automatically loaded if it is inside your classpath, ok. But if you have defined some validation bean in your Configuration class or in your XML application-dao.xml, it could raise some errors like these one.

Maybe having a look at your applicationContext*.xml should help us.
Maybe having a look at your pom.xml (if you are using maven) should help too.

Comment: i have added the classpath and the application context

Comment: `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and `<context:component-scan base-package="com.seprof.web.controller" />` are maybe declared twice in your `webapp-servlet.xml` file and in your `applicationContext.xml` file. I usually set these tags inside the `webapp-servlet.xml`.

Comment: Using these bean in my configuration: `<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />`. Try to add it as default validator and see what happens.

Comment: I have found these one too, in order to scan the annotated class: `<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
     p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
     p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
     p:packagesToScan="com.companyName.annotated.pojos.to.scan"/>`

Comment: in fact i have just a dispatcher-servlet.xml and the application context is inside

Comment: Hello, did you try to add the bean with `id="validator"` I have previously suggested to see if making a default validator available will resolve the not found error you have ?

I have a validation provider too: I use hibernate validator with the following jar: `hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-4.1.0.Final`

Comment: yes i have added the `id="validator"` but always the same exception.
byroad the exception appear when i copy the jar `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar` to the folder lib with or without adding to the build path.

Comment: i try to add `hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar` to the classpath and the exception disappear.

Comment: Yes you've got it, it is because we need to add a validation provider.
The validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar alone is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Check your classpath :
- are you sure that validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar is inside ?
- Don't you have some conflicts with your libs ?

Comment: i have added the classpath and the application context